# Have we talked about voting yet?

Tags: discussion, voting

Let's talk voting. No, not the kind where you go in the little booth and vote for the person less likely to break the government, but the kind where you as a member of the community rank posts by their usefulness, using upvotes and downvotes to help push the best material to the top and the worst content to the bottom.

Voting plays a key role in our community's health. The more content that's voted, the better organized it becomes. What's more, this divvies up more power to the community so community members can take a larger role in site moderation activities.

There are two voting badges that tell us how we're doing as a community in terms of voting. There's the [image: Vox Populi Badge] badge, which you can earn by using up all 40 of your votes in a single day.  Also, there's the [image: Suffrage Badge] badge, which you can  earn by using at least 30 votes in a single day.

The trick to claiming the Vox Populi badge is to use at least 10 votes on questions, which get ranked on the [top questions by votes](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) page. If you only vote on answers, you're limited to only 30 votes. This limitation helps ensure we don't forget to vote on questions too.

Now, many of you might not be interested in the flair, and that's fine. When we look at the badges page and see that a lot of users have earned these participation badges, it is a small sign that we're doing the right things to create a useful site. Moreover, it helps show that there are people out there who care about its success.

At the time of this writing, I'm not on the list for either one of those two badges, so I'm going through the [top questions](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) and am voting on content. I welcome you to join me. If you find anything interesting or noteworthy, jump into our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8874/freelancing) and share a link. Please don't be shy. The room is pretty quiet, and there's just a few of us who occasionally drop by. There's really no rules in chat other than just be nice, so it's low pressure.

This is also a good time to go through and improve posts by making suggested edits or to flag content that needs moderator attention.