# Down Votes: The most accessible and most powerful tools of community moderation

Tags: discussion, support, voting, down-votes

We've [talked about voting before](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148/have-we-talked-about-voting-yet) and how important it is for the community's health. While up votes grant more privileges to members of our community, it's down votes that I wish to talk about today, as it's down votes that help keep poor quality content from eclipsing the good quality content on the site.

I won't cite examples here, but I'm sure you've seen, or will eventually see, lower quality answers appearing above higher quality answers. This is a huge disservice to the folks who took the time to write great content, and we all have the power to fix this. :)

Down votes are perhaps the most accessible and most powerful tools of community moderation. It only takes [125 reputation to down vote questions and answers](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down). That means a large majority of the regular contributors of this site have the power to determine what content appears at the *top* and what content appears at the *bottom*.  Down votes aren't about the people. Instead, down votes are about making sure content that doesn't quite meet our quality standards or that is dangerous or incorrect appears *below* content that is correct, accurate, and that explains why and how.

If you don't want to leave a comment or don't feel comfortable doing so, that's fine.  ***Voting is completely anonymous.*** If you down vote a post, you are in no way obligated to leave a comment. This is *encouraged*, but it is not *required*. The actual act of voting, of pushing the content down (or up for up votes) is more important, so don't let commenting discourage you.

If you do comment, separate the act of voting from the act of commenting. On posts I down vote, I generally leave a friendly comment such as this:

> Hello user, welcome to Freelancing SE. On our Q&A site, we're generally looking for answers that address the full question and teach, not just tell. Consider making an [edit] to improve this post and prevent it from possibly being removed. If you need more guidance, check out [ask] for more details.
>
> > <sub>[edit] is a short code link for the user to edit the post, and [ask] and [answer] are short code links for linking to the ["How to Ask"](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to Answer"](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) help center pages.</sub>

If needed, moderators are happy to step in and leave comments with tips on how to improve a post. Such information need not come from the voters themselves.

So if you see low quality content that isn't useful because it doesn't provide detailed explanations, doesn't answer the question, or makes assumptions that may not be correct, ***take action and push that content to the bottom of the page.*** If a user comes back later and edits and improves the post later, review the content, and consider changing your vote.  Remember, votes on edited and improved posts can always be changed anytime after the edit, so long as your vote was cast prior to the edits.

Our site has come a long way and is full of useful content. By using all of the moderation tools in our toolbox, we ensure that the standards we've set as a community remain high so we continue to provide value for years to come!